# как переделать макет с помощью inline-block?

Tags: css, css3, html5

flex:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      1
    </header>
    <main>
      <aside>
        2
      </aside>
      <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
          5
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          4
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
      3
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS3:

```
html{height: 100%;}
body{font: 18px 'Arial'; height: 100%; margin: 0;}
.container{min-height: 100%; max-width: 1280px; margin: 0 auto; display: flex; flex-direction: column;}
 
header, aside, footer{padding: 15px;}
header, footer{color: #fff; background-color: #0066ff; border: 2px solid #000;}
header{background-color: #0066ff;}
 
main{display: flex; flex-grow: 1;}
aside{flex-basis: 200px; flex-shrink: 0; border-left: 2px solid #000; border-right: 2px solid #000;}
aside, .row{background-color: #ffcc00;}
 
.content{border-right: 2px solid #000; flex-grow: 1;}
.row{padding: 15px; border-bottom: 2px solid #000;}
.text{padding: 15px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
html{height: 100%;}
body{font: 18px 'Arial'; height: 100%; margin: 0;}
.container{min-height: 100%; max-width: 1280px; margin: 0 auto;}
 
header, aside, footer{padding: 15px;}
header, footer{color: #fff; background-color: #0066ff; border: 2px solid #000; min-height:20vh;}
header{background-color: #0066ff;}
 
main{min-height:60vh;}
aside{ border-left: 2px solid #000; border-right: 2px solid #000; float:left; display: inline-block; width: 30%; min-height: 60vh;}
aside, .row{background-color: #ffcc00;}
 
.content{border-right: 2px solid #000; display: inline-block; width: 70%; min-height: 60vh;}
.row{padding: 15px; border-bottom: 2px solid #000;}
.text{padding: 15px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header>
      1
    </header>
    <main>
      <aside>
        2
      </aside>
      <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
          5
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          4
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
      3
    </footer>
  </div>
```